# Login to account from any computer

Tags: networking

At my school, we have a large network of computers. Each department has its own switch with all the computers connected to it, and each switch is connected to the main router or server. I can login to any computer with my username and password and my files will be there. How is this done and how could it be replicated for a small home or business with about 10 computers or less?

Comment: Its done with a Domain Server. Expensive Operating System and hardware.

Comment: You can probably get this effect for your home with a much simpler setup than your school uses (unless your home is divided into departments that each has its own switch).

Comment: any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, I cannot tell you exactly how is your school configured to do so, but I can give you some ideas on how to implement this.

You don't specify whether your school uses `Windows` or `Linux` systems, so I'll mention both.

For `Windows` systems, there is the `Active Directory`, which basically is a centralized database of accounts and users information that along with a filesystem like `DFS` can store all the data within a central server and then, each time a user logs in, the information is retrieved from this central server and the session started with that info.

- [What is Active Directory?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory)
- [How to implement Active directory?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742437.aspx)
- [What is DFS?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779627%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

For Linux systems, the easier way to implement this is with the power of PAM. The idea is very similar to the described above - There will be one (or several) central servers which store information and homes of users, and the clients will be configured to mount this remote central home and start the session with it.

- [What is PAM?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module)
- [How To Use PAM to Configure Authentication on an Ubuntu 12.04 VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps)